# How to avoid excessive dataframe query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Consider there is spark job has multiple dataframe transitions

```
val baseDF1 = spark.sql(s"select *  from db.table1 where condition1='blah'")
val baseDF2 = spark.sql(s"select *  from db.table2 where condition2='blah'")
val df3 = basedDF1.join(baseDF12, basedDF1("col1") <=> basedDF1("col2"))
val df4 = df3.withcolumn("col3").withColumnRename("col4", "newcol4")
val df5 = df4.groupBy("groupbycol").agg(expr("coalesce(first(col5, false))"))
val df6 = df5.withColumn("level1", col("coalesce(first(col5, false))")(0))
  .withColumn("level2", col("coalesce(first(col5, false))")(1))
  .withColumn("level3", col("coalesce(first(col5, false))")(2))
  .withColumn("level4", col("coalesce(first(col5, false))")(3))
  .withColumn("level5", col("coalesce(first(col5, false))")(4))
  .drop("coalesce(first(col5, false))")
```

I just wondering how Spark generate the spark SQL logic, is it going to generate the query-like transaction for each data frame, i.e

```
df1 = select * ....   
df2 = select * .... 
df3 = df1.join.df2  // spark takes content from df1/df2 instead run each query again for joining
....
df6 = ...
```

or generate large query by the end of the last dataframe

```
df6 = select coalesce(first(col5, false)).. from ((select * from table1) join (select * from table2 ) on blah ) group by blah 2...
```

All I trying to figure out, is how to avoid Spark generate huge query-like logic instead I can let Spark "Commit" somewhere to avoid huge long transaction

the reason behind the inquiry is because current spark job threw following exception

```
19/12/17 10:57:55 ERROR CodeGenerator: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 567, Column 28: Redefinition of parameter "agg_expr_21"
```

Comment: `df6.explain(true)` should offer some insight into how Spark generates the DAG internally. It can be difficult to understand at first, but rewarding in the long run.

Comment: It's a bug.See, for example, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19984 which generates the same message, but for a different reason.

Committing is not a goer.

Build the statements in steps, and see where the error crops up, and try to work around it. 

The query is not excessive and your request is quite excessive to answer!

Stages are the result with Catalyst fusing code together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark has two operations - transformation and action.

Transformation happens when a DF is being built using various operations like - select, join, filter etc. It is read to be executed but has not done any work yet, it is being lazy. These transformations can be composed to make new transformation which you do while operating on predefined dataframes, like `basedDF1.join(baseDF12, basedDF1("col1") <=> basedDF1("col2"))`. But again nothing has run.

Action happens when certain operations are called like save, collect, show etc. This is when real work happens. Here each and every 'transformation' that was defined before with be either executed or retrieved from cache. You can save a lot of work for Spark if you can cache some of the complex steps. This can also simplify the plan.

```
val baseDF1 = spark.sql(s"select *  from db.table1 where condition1='blah'")
val baseDF2 = spark.sql(s"select *  from db.table2 where condition2='blah'")
baseDF1.cache()
baseDF2.cache()
val df3 = basedDF1.join(baseDF12, basedDF1("col1") <=> basedDF1("col2"))

val df4 = baseDF1.join(baseDF12, basedDF1("col2") === basedDF1("col3"))// different join
```

When df4 is executed after df3, it won't be selecting from db.table1 and db.table2 but rather reading baseDF1 and baseDF2 from cache. The plan will look simpler too.
if some reason cache is gone then Spark will recompute baseDF1 and baseDF2 as they were defined, so it knows its lineage but didn't execute it.

You can also use checkpoint to break up the lineage of overall execution, hence simplify it. I think this can help your case.

I have also saved intermediate dataframe to a temporary file and read It back as a dataframe and use it down the line. This breaks up the complexity at the cost of extra io. I won’t recommend it unless other methods didn’t work.

I am not sure about the error you are getting.

Comment: Checkpoint will break up a rdd’s complex lineage into steps, hence simply it. Does it make sence?

Comment: I have also saved intermediate dataframe into a file, read it back and use it down the line. This helped in breaking up the complexity at the cost of extra io.

Comment: I thought checkpointing was to make recovery simpler as in it need not always go back too long. But I grant you it is confusing. May be you are correct.

Comment: Yes that is correct too. As intermediate state is check pointed to a stable file the next step in the execution will depend in this intermediate file not on its complex lineage. It does both - simply and faster recovery. Thought faster recovery is the intention